# How to move PV from one kubernetes node to another

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I have a k8s cluster which uses rancher.io/local-path.
There is a PV there

```
    $ kubectl describe pv pvc-979af6ff-3617-4707-8a2c-b6c4ac00043f
    Name:              pvc-979af6ff-3617-4707-8a2c-b6c4ac00043f
    Labels:            <none>
    Annotations:       pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: rancher.io/local-path
    Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
    StorageClass:      local-path
    Status:            Bound
    Claim:             gitlab/gitlab-prometheus-server
    Reclaim Policy:    Delete
    Access Modes:      RWO
    VolumeMode:        Filesystem
    Capacity:          8Gi
    Node Affinity:     
      Required Terms:  
        Term 0:        kubernetes.io/hostname in [agent-1]
    Message:           
    Source:
        Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
        Path:          /var/lib/rancher/k3s/storage/pvc-979af6ff-3617-4707-8a2c-b6c4ac00043f_gitlab_gitlab-prometheus-server
        HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
    Events:            <none>
```

I would like to move that PV to another node, agetn-5. How can I achieve that?
Important point that PV in question is `rancher.io/local-path` provisioned.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. You will mostly likely need to manually copy the data to the new volume. This is one of many reasons why network disks like block storage are typical for k8s.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, there is no direct way of moving a `rancher.io/local-path` pv from one host to another, since the data is only available on the node the pv has been provisioned on.

So to move the pv, the data has to be moved first. Then the pv has to be patched to point to the new host.

An easy way would be to ssh into the node and move the data using rsync. The location of the pv in the filesystem can be found by checking `spec.hostPath.path` of the pv.

Before moving the data, the replicaset accessing the pv should be scaled to 0.

```
kubectl -n $namespace scale --replicas=0 $deployment

pv="$name_of_pv_to_move"
pvpath=$(kubectl get pv $pv -o jsonpath='{.spec.hostPath.path}')

ssh -A root@node1 rsync -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
  -rav $pvpath root@node2:$pvpath
```

For rsync to work like that, obviously ssh access has to work on both hosts and ssh key has to be in ssh-agent.

The fields that need to be changed in the pv are immutable, so we have to force the changes causing the api to recreate the pv. Also the `pv-protection` finalizer needs to be removed, otherwise the patch command will not be successful.

```
pv="$name_of_pv_to_move"
newhostname="$new_host_name"

kubectl patch pv $pv -p \
  '{"spec":{"nodeAffinity":{"required":{"nodeSelectorTerms": 
     [{"matchExpressions": [{"key":"kubernetes.io/hostname",
     "operator": "In","values":["NEWHOSTNAME"]}]}]}}}}' \
  --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply --force -f - & ; sleep 1 ; \
  kubectl patch pv $pv --type='json' -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/metadata/finalizers/0"}]'
```

After that, the deployment can be scaled up again and the pod accessing the moved pv will be scheduled on the new host.

Comment: Thanks! Just happened upon the same task while playing around with my homelab setup and the pv-protection finalizer and `--force` to recreate the resource were exactly the details that I was missing. Additional kudos for generalizing your answer in such a way as to be useful for scripting.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to do this in a single step.

But you can:

1. Access the K8s cluster where PVC exists
2. Create a Deployment (or single Pod) that mounts PVC on the path you prefer (Example /xyz)
3. Run

```
   kubectl -n NAMESPACE cp POD_NAME:/xyz /tmp/
```

to locally copy the contents of the /xyz folder to the /tmp path

4. Logout from K8s cluster
5. Login to the K8s cluster where data will be migrated
6. Create new PVC
7. Create a Deployment (or Single Pod) that mounts the PVC on the path you prefer (Example /new-xyz)
8. Run

```
   kubectl -n NAMESPACE cp /tmp/xyz/ POD_NAME:/new-xyz/
```

to copy the local content to the path /new-xyz